# Pagos con tarjeta de credito devuelve cc_rejected_other_reason

Tags: php, mercadopago

Ayer configure un sitio en modo producción para MercadoPago y estoy intentando hacer un pago con tarjeta de crédito, pero para todos los casos me da RECHAZADA y en detalles dice **cc_rejected_other_reason**

Configure todo el sitio con las credenciales de producción y tengo el SSL.
En MercadoPago Developers entre a este link >> https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/response-handling/ y me dice que **cc_rejected_other_reason** quiere decir que **payment_method_id no procesó el pago**. WOW! ¿QUE SIGNIFICA?

Los pagos en efectivo como PagoFacil o RapiPago funcionan OK

Los parametros que envio son los siguientes:

```
transaction_amount:88
tokenCard:ad07ea43c6d97a7th54gs8bbcce8879e
token_mercadopago:<aqui paso mi token productivo, pero no lo publico por seguridad>
description:PUBLICACION POR 30 días
payment_method_id:visa
cuota:1
tipo_pago:credit_card
issuerId:999
```

Esta es la respuesta:

```
{"status":201,
"response":
{   
    "id":3254686262,
    "date_created":
    "2017-12-16T05:43:54.000-04:00",
    "date_approved":null,
    "date_last_updated":"2017-12-16T05:43:55.000-04:00",
    "date_of_expiration":null,
    "money_release_date":null,
    "operation_type":"regular_payment",
    "issuer_id":"999", <-- pongo otro numero por seguridad 
    "payment_method_id":"visa",
    "payment_type_id":"credit_card",
    "status":"rejected",
    "status_detail":"cc_rejected_other_reason",
    "currency_id":"ARS",
    "description":"PUBLICACION POR 30 días",
    "live_mode":true,
    "sponsor_id":null,
    "authorization_code":null,
    "money_release_schema":null,
    "counter_currency":null,
    "collector_id":264444446,
    "payer":
    {
        "type":"guest",
        "id":null,
        "email":"micorreo@gmail.com",
        "identification":
        {
            "type":"DNI",
            "number":"<aqui va mi nro de documento>"
        },
        "phone":
        {
            "area_code":"011",
            "number":"<mi numero de telefono>",
            "extension":""
        },
        "first_name":"Diego",
        "last_name":"Hern\\u00E1ndez",
        "entity_type":null
    },
    "metadata":[],
    "additional_info":[],
    "order":[],
    "external_reference":null,
    "transaction_amount":88,
    "transaction_amount_refunded":0,
    "coupon_amount":0,
    "differential_pricing_id":null,
    "deduction_schema":null,
    "transaction_details":
    {
        "net_received_amount":0,
        "total_paid_amount":88,
        "overpaid_amount":0,
        "external_resource_url":null,
        "installment_amount":88,
        "financial_institution":null,
        "payment_method_reference_id":null,
        "payable_deferral_period":null,
        "acquirer_reference":null},
        "fee_details":[],
        "captured":true,
        "binary_mode":false,
        "call_for_authorize_id":null,
        "statement_descriptor":"WWW.MERCADOPAGO.COM",
        "installments":1,
        "card":
        {
            "id":null,
            "first_six_digits":"999999", <-- aqui vienen bien, pero pongo otro numero
            "last_four_digits":"9999", <-- aca tambien pero pongo otro numero
            "expiration_month":1,
            "expiration_year":2018,
            "date_created":"2017-12-16T05:43:54.000-04:00",
            "date_last_updated":"2017-12-16T05:43:54.000-04:00",
            "cardholder":
            {
                "name":"DIEGO HERNANDEZ",
                "identification":
                {
                    "number":"<mi numero de documento>",
                    "type":"DNI"
                }
            }
        },
        "notification_url":null,
        "refunds":[],
        "processing_mode":"aggregator",
        "merchant_account_id":null,
        "acquirer":null,
        "merchant_number":null,
        "acquirer_reconciliation":[]
    }
}
```

También hice una prueba con una tarjeta de crédito de AMEX y me tira el mismo error.

Las tarjetas de créditos son mías y están habilitadas.

¿Tiene algo que ver este error con que yo sea el titular de MercadoPago y este usando mis tarjetas de crédito?

También aclaro que tengo una cuenta comprador (no cuenta vendedor) en MercadoPago y no asocie ninguna cuenta bancaria aún.

Agradecería muchísimo que alguien pueda ayudarme ya que no encuentro ningún error al respecto.

Desde ya muchas gracias!
Saludos, Diego

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontre cual era el problema!

Primero, si tenemos una cuenta de mercadopago vinculada con nuestro numero de documento, no podemos usar tarjetas de creditos que esten asociadas a ese nro de documento. Yo era titular de esas dos tarjetas y por eso no funcionaron.

Segundo, deben tener una cuenta vendedor. Cuando crean la cuenta en mercadopago, tienen una cuenta personal pero no como vendedor. El sistema de mercadopago les ofrece la posibilidad de pasarse a cuenta vendedor por 30 dias de prueba. No les cobra nada igual. Solo se paga la comicion por una venta. Si no se hace esto, no se puede abonar con tarjeta. Ademas con la cuenta  vendedor ofrecen cuotas sin interes al comprador.

La tercera, si prueban con una tarjeta de credito de otra persona, prueben con montos superiores a 1 peso ARS. En la documentacion de mercadopago aclara que hay tarjetas de credito que no aceptan montos de 1 peso. Yo probe con un importe de 88 pesos y funciono.

Disculprn que mi explicacion sea extensa pero es necesario para otro que tenga el mismo problema.

Saludos!
Diego

Comment: Gracias por responder tu propia duda, hoy, dos años y medio más tarde, sigue pasando. Borré las tarjetas de mi cuenta de MercadoPago y pude pagar satisfactoriamente en la página.

Answer (score -1):

Amén de que la pregunta ya esté respondida satisfactoriamente, dejo esto por si a alguien con el mismo problema le sirve.

Dicho código también se recibe cuando estamos usando *tokens* de TEST y se introduce una tarjeta válida (de un portador que no es el usuario que va a recibir el dinero, etc). Por ende, se pueden probar *tokens* de TEST en ambientes de desarrollo e incluso el que se usará en producción, y dichas requests devolverán un status **201**, pero no se le cobrará al propietario de la tarjeta, y el código de response['status_detail'] será justamente **"cc_rejected_other_reason"**.

Espero que a alguien le sirva.
Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte!!! podrias mirar el [tour] para saber como funcionamos. Tambien mira [answer]